# select with angular2 in firefox 44

Tags: angular, firefox, select

I have next select:

```
<select id="type"
        name="type"
        class="b-form__input"
        [(ngModel)]="currentDoc.type">
    <option *ngFor="let fileType of fileTypes" [ngValue]="fileType">{{ fileType.value }}</option>
</select>
```

If I just open form with that select and press submit (without select changing) then ngModel will be null although in Firefox 44 or 29  select as value has first option.

How to solve that problem? How to enforce angular to set first option as ngModel value in firefox?

Comment: try changing [ngValue] to [value]

Comment: @nikhilmehta I'm tried, doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the default value of model:

```
currentDoc{
    type: ".doc"
  }
```

You can check plunker demo here: https://plnkr.co/edit/lGFyPVaIRRXODjdmBD7E?p=preview

Comment: It's ok, I know. But I want to solve problem by changing templates only, not my *.ts files.

Comment: @dimedrol90 if you are not setting currentDoc.type how do you expect it to reflect it into html

Comment: @nikhilmehta I agree with you. I must set currentDoc.type. But my problem is old Firefox. In case of firefox 50 if currentDoc.type is null then select is empty. But in case firefox 44/29 when form is loaded and currentDoc.type is null, select as value has first option. Select has value, but in angular linked [(ngModel)] is null. And I trying to solve this problem by changing HTML template. But it seems that it's impossible